# Relating to $( a ^ b ) + c = d$ and $( a ^ b ) - c = d$

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a way of deducing the smallest integer values for $a, b$ and $c$ that satisfy
either

$( a ^ b ) + c = d$

or

$( a ^ b ) - c = d$

such that the addition $( a + b + c )$ is the smallest possible integer?

I am wanting to do this for some very large integer values up to approximately
14 000 000 000 000 digits long.
I may have to work with some smaller numbers to start with however.

I could write a computer program to determine some numbers but I was wondering if there is some higher level mathematics involved that could provide a solution please.

Comment: For any positive $d$, $x^1-(x-d)=d$, so the required sum can be $x+1+(x-d)$. Now the sum can be arbitrarily negative by reducing $x$.

Comment: vadim123.
Imagine if the number for d is now = 13579246812435687903215137539757
or any long number you care to imagine.
What then are the smallest numbers for a, b and c respectively?

I am looking for a way to see if they can be determined mathematically without using a computer program to do so that uses loops to find any solution.

Comment: peterwhy.
What if there are no solutions for some values of d
where c = 0 or even c = 1 ?

Comment: There is always a solution $(d-1)^1+1 = d$, so the sum is $(d-1)+1+1 = d+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $b>1$ and  $a^b\approx d$ then $(a\pm1)^b$ differs from $a$ by $\approx ba^{b-1}\approx\frac{bd}{a}$, hence we can achieve $c\approx \frac{bd}a$ or better. For given $b$, we will have $a\approx \sqrt[b]d$, hence 
$$ a+b+c\approx \sqrt[b]d +b+\frac{bd}{\sqrt[b]d}.$$
In this light, the best choce seems to be $b=2$ as it keeps the last summand small. Anything better than that is "luck", e.g. if $d$ happens to be awfully close to some high (odd) power.
Computationally, it is not too problematic to compute $a=\lfloor \sqrt[b]d\rfloor $ for $b=2,3,\ldots$ and determine the $c$ belonging to $a^b$ and $(a+1)^b$ until you reach $a<10$ say. After that try the obvious best choices of $b,c$ for $a=2,\ldots , 9$ accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :-)
I may have to test the idea programatically.

However consider d = 13579246812435687903215137539757
( that I mentioned in an earlier comment ).

If b = 3685002959623735 then
3685002959623735 X 3685002959623735
= 13579246812435686322652775350225

c = 13579246812435687903215137539757 - 13579246812435686322652775350225
= 1580562362189532

You see that the value for c is still quite large.
I will have to test other values for b to see how small c can become.
[continued in next comment]

Comment: I may end up determining that the ideal value for b may be say 2 for a certain range of numbers and gradually higher as the value for d grows larger.